# SQLAlchemy ForeignKey in child table without relationship in parent table

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I stumbled on a code and was expecting it to throw some errors due to its lack of backward ref to the parent table. But to my surprise, everything ran fine and even the Database relationships were built without a hitch.

```
class City(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'city'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)


class Place(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'place'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("city.id"), nullable=True)
```

Can anyone explain why this happened ?

```
class City(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'city'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship("User", backref='place')



class Place(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'place'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("city.id"), nullable=True)
```